# Suggestions to understand complexities

Tags: group-theory, algorithms, cryptography, combinatorial-group-theory, braid-groups

I am currently working on pure math based cryptography,and I haven't ever studied Complexities. I need to understand how complexities of any algorithm works from a mathematical point of view. For example, the left canonical form of a word with word length l (on generators of the braid group) can be computed in time O(l^2*logn). To understand this proof,I will need some basic understanding of complexities in general,so any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Here's a good [intuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/487278/3813411) explanation of big-O.

Comment: https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/